# check if pdf contain image JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-lib.js

i'm using pdfjsLib to check the data of my pdf.

After 3 days i'm still stuck...

I can find text inside my pdf but i don't know how to check if my PDF contain and image or not.Any ideas ?

here a sample of my code (stackItem == url of pdf file)

```
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(stackItem);
    loadingTask.promise
      .then(function (doc: { numPages: any; getMetadata: () => Promise<any>; getPage: (arg0: any) => Promise<any>; }) {
        const numPages = doc.numPages;
        console.log("# Document Loaded");
        console.log("Number of Pages: " + numPages);
        console.log();

        let lastPromise;
        lastPromise = doc.getMetadata().then(function (data: { info: any; metadata: { getAll: () => any; }; }) {
          console.log("# Metadata Is Loaded");
          console.log("## Info");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.info, null, 2));
          if (data.metadata) {
            console.log("## Metadata");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.metadata.getAll()),);
          }
        });

        const loadPage = function (pageNum: string) {
          return doc.getPage(pageNum).then(function (page: { getViewport: (arg0: { scale: number; }) => any; getTextContent: () => Promise<any>; cleanup: () => void; }) {
            console.log("# Page " + pageNum);
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.0 });
            console.log("Size: " + viewport.width + "x" + viewport.height);
            console.log();
            return page
              .getTextContent()
              .then(function (content: { items: any[]; }) {
                const strings = content.items.map(function (item: { str: any; }) {
                  return item.str;
                });
                console.log("## Text Content");
                console.log(strings.join(" "));
                page.cleanup();
              })
              .then(function () {
                console.log();
              });
          });
        };
        // Loading of the first page will wait on metadata and subsequent loadings
        // will wait on the previous pages.
        for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
          lastPromise = lastPromise.then(loadPage.bind(null, i));
        }
        return lastPromise;
      })
      .then(
        function () {
          console.log("# End of Document");
        },
        function (err: string) {
          console.error("Error: " + err);
        }
      );
```

thx

Comment: You should be looking for Image XObjects. They have /Type /XObject and /Subtype /Image and can be found in the /Resources of a page (or, since they are inheritable, in the /Resources for any ancestor page tree node for the page).

In the page content itself, they will be introduced with the Do operator, for example /Im1 Do. However, you must distinguish them from Form XObjects, which are introduced the same way but have /Subtype /Form.

Comment: thx @johnwhitington but i don't find how to do it in JS can you explain me ?

Comment: thx @KJ but i don't find how to do it in JS can you explain me ?